# overriding basePAth for Edit or ShowButton

Tags: react-admin

In reference to this: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/1491

That is not overriding the url that gets called.

I thought this meant to change the basePath of the URL that hoes to the API not the internal one to the frontend site, hopefully that makes sense.

So essentially I want to override the basePath so I can call a different URL on the backend side. If this is not what was intended , how can I override a action of the EditButton or ShowButton to call a different URL?

Or the other option that I can think of is: if we have a way to override the attribute that gets picked at the moment the button gets clicked, that is for an instance for complex structures instead of sending the id to lookup you could use something like: user.id.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to this is to customise the dataProvider. But I don't see it as a clean solution to have to customise the dataProvider for such a case scenario :(